# recyclerview filter in is not working in android studio

Tags: android-recyclerview

I have coded getFilter() in adapter class and onQueryTextChange in mainactivity but don't know whats the prob it is not filtering nor searching please help I need to implement a search filter RecyclerView the list must be filtered while typing.

This part is in my Mainactivity

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
        searchView.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                BalanceReportAdapter myClass = new BalanceReportAdapter(jsonResponses, 
                BalanceReport.this);
                myClass.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });
        return  super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

This part is in my Adapter.class

```
Filter filter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constaint) {

            List<BalanceReportModel> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

            if (constaint.toString().isEmpty()) {
                filteredList.addAll(retrievedResponses);
                Log.e("you are here1",filteredList.toString());
            } else {
                for (BalanceReportModel patient : retrievedResponsesAll) {
                    if 
       
    (patient.getcustomer().toLowerCase().contains(constaint.toString().toLowerCase()))
                    {
                        filteredList.add(patient);
                    }
                }
                Log.e("you are here2",retrievedResponses.toString());
            }

            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = filteredList;
            return filterResults;
        }

        @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults filterResults) {
            Log.e("you are here3",filterResults.toString());
            retrievedResponses.clear();
            retrievedResponses.addAll((Collection<? extends BalanceReportModel>) filterResults.values);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
```

I have tried several times but not yet succeeded Please someone help me. Is there any other way to make it work?
Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: This is the activity

Comment: Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are creating a new adapter each time in your `onQueryTextChange`

This instance of adapter is not assigned to recyclerView anywhere after that. I would recommend having one instance of adapter somewhere at the top-level and just call for that instance, and `.filter` logic

Comment: Thank you for the reply but i dont know how to do it. I tried many ways but no result.